# Where do clan invites appear?

Tags: call-of-duty-advanced-warfare

I've sent two friends clan invites while they were offline.  They don't know where to find the invites that were sent.  Where do these invites appear in the menus?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's under Operator > Clans > Invites > Invites from the multiplayer menu.

[image]

Answer (score -3):

i believe it should be always in you barracks page located somewhere in the multiplier menu.

Comment: Unfortunately not an especially good answer since it sounds more like a guess. Try making it more "You will find it in..." rather than "I believe it's in..."

Comment: 'Somewhere' doesn't tell me where to find it.